# Laravel 5 share data with all views

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've this code and want to share all in views of the project, how could I do ??

```
        $id_user = Auth::user()->id;

        $data['modulos'] = Permissaousuario::Modulo($id_user);

        $id_modulo = DB::table('modulos')
        ->where('rota','like','%ensaio%')
        ->pluck('id');

        $data['areas'] = Permissaousuario::Area($id_user,$id_modulo);
        $data['permissoes'] = Permissaousuario::Permissao($id_user,$id_modulo);
        $data['usuario'] = Auth::user();

        return view('ensaio.home')->with($data);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Share it with `view()->share()` in your `AppServiceProvider`'s `boot` method:

```php
public function boot()
{
    $id = Auth::id();

    $modulos = DB::table('modulos')->where('rota', 'like', '%ensaio%')->pluck('id');

    view()->share([
        'usuario'    => Auth::user(),
        'modulos'    => Permissaousuario::Modulo($id),
        'areas'      => Permissaousuario::Area($id, $modulos),
        'permissoes' => Permissaousuario::Permissao($id, $modulos),
    ]);
}
```

The file is located here: `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

Comment: doenst work, looks like the boot method dont get the user from the session, if I dd(Auth::user()); in the view I can see my session, but in boot method using the exemple doenst work.